# Angular Typeahead - Static Array : Not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I picked the code from the angular bootstrap type-ahead folder and tweaked it to include the library dependencies.

[type-ahead](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead/docs)

When I launch the html, the model seems to be correctly bound but the typeahead suggestions are not showing up as it is in the documentation.

I seem to be missing something.

My Code [here](http://pastebin.com/M8T91CvZ).

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: What problem you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this plnker. It works with the same details.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tf7AWgq2tH6ZBZjNgg6V?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Jayram, Yes it works. I noticed that in your example.js you have this line on top : angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
Is that really required?

Comment: Yeah. It is required to pass the dependency to the function in angularjs for accessing the angular ui functionality.